# I get an error incompatible types TFormClass and Class reference

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am improving a Delphi program...
There is a procedure that expects a `TFormClass` argument `(class of TForm)`.

I passed in TForm1 or like and it did not like. E.g. `procname(TForm1);`
There are other forms in the program that are passed in similarly in the program,
yet there is no such compilation errors for them.

E.g. there is another form that is passed and it is defined as

```
type TForm4 = class(TForm)
....
procname(TForm4);
```

This does not cause a compilation error.

My form is defined as type

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)...
```

It looks similar, right?  What may be the reason this is not accepted by the compiler?

Why are the others accepted ? What may be the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Better copy paste the _exact_ pieces of code. I don't believe we can see the error part here.

Comment: Figured out... a unit redefines tform , so it make some of those exception special

Comment: You didn't *redefine* TForm,  you defined a new class with the same name.  The difference is subtle, yet, so important.

Comment: Perhaps you could [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67898/54262) your question with the solution you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I did not write this program. I improved it..
The program had a unit which was imported in all units where the problem did not come up.

let it be called "UnitWithAdditionalTFormDotDefinitions".

The solution was easy.

at the beginning of the unit n the this error message originated, I changed the uses statement.

E,g.

uses Unit1,Unit2,Forms;  // this was the original state or similar

After

uses Unit1,Unit2,Forms,UnitWithAdditionalTFormDot;